# trouble downloading Django on Mac

Tags: django

I have had problems downloading anything onto my mac (OS x 10.5.4).

So far I have successfully downloaded Python 3.4, PIP (through terminal), and when I try to download Django through terminal (sudo pip install Django==1.6.4) I get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 271, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2173, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1906, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.5.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip.util import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.5.egg/pip/util.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip.vendor.distlib import version
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.5.egg/pip/vendor/distlib/version.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .compat import string_types
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.5.egg/pip/vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 276
    return b''
```

Comment: Is that the whole message? Don't you see an `ImportError` at the bottom?

Comment: it also has SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Nothing else after

Comment: Why do you want to use python 3.4 instead of the version that comes with osx? (And why are you using such an old version of osx?)

Comment: Your `pip` appears to be using Python 2.5. You can confirm this by typing `pip --version`. Check to see if you have a `pip-3.4` (e.g. `which pip-3.4`) installed on your system. Also, it would be a good idea to use a virtualenv with the Python version you desire (this will choose and install the correct pip for you).

Answer (score -1):

1. Install [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) and [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), here's a nice tutorial: https://jamie.curle.io/blog/installing-pip-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-on-os-x/
2. Create a virtualenv with the python version you want to use: `mkvirtualenv my_virtual_env -p python3.4`.
3. You should be "inside" your virtualenv (if you're not do: `workon my_virtual_env`). Now you can install Django and all you want:

   ```
   (my_virtual_env) user@host$ pip install Django==1.6
   ```

That `(my_virtual_env)` thing you see indicates what virtualenv is active. Welcome to the virtualenv world. Please read the docs.